# GNAT GPL Ada fails will linkage error when cross-compiling for the Raspberry pi

Tags: cross-compiling, ada, gnat

I am trying to build a simple "hello_there" Ada app to run on a Raspberry Pi 2/Raspbian machine but have come across a linkage issue.

So far, I've done the following and had the following issues:

1. Downloaded the "Raspberry Pi 2 Linux" GNAT GPL Ada toolchain for cross compiling (linux-on-linux) on the host machine (Ubuntu 16.04)
2. Ran "doinstall" on the  host  machine successfully.
3. Created a simple "hello_there.adb"  file which just prints a message  to the console.
4. Ran {INSTALL_ROOT}/*gnat-gpl-2016-raspberrypi-linux-linux-bin/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gnatmake -v hello_there.adb* to build this small app.
5. That complained that the **crt1.o** | **crti.o** | **crtn.o** files cannot be found and since I couldn't use the ones under */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*  on  the host machine (as I assume, these can only be used for a  x86 target) the only solution I could find was to copy these files from the target machine which are located under */usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf* to the gnatmake command dir. That stopped the linker complaining about these.
6. Ran again {INSTALL_ROOT}/*gnat-gpl-2016-raspberrypi-linux-linux-bin/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gnatmake -v hello_there.adb* but now the linker is complaining with the following error:

   *{INSTALL_ROOT}/gnat-gpl-2016-raspberrypi-linux-linux-bin/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/ld: **cannot find -lc***

   It looks like compilation and binding complete fine but but linking fails. The full output is the following:

   ```
   GNATMAKE GPL 2016 (20160515-49)
   Copyright (C) 1992-2016, Free Software Foundation, Inc.
     "hello_there.ali" being checked ...
     -> "hello_there.ali" missing.
   arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -c hello_there.adb
   End of compilation
   arm-linux-gnueabihf-gnatbind -x hello_there.ali
   arm-linux-gnueabihf-gnatlink hello_there.ali
   /home/savvas/opt/GNAT/gnat-gpl-2016-raspberrypi-linux-linux-bin/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9.4/ld: cannot find -lc
   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
   arm-linux-gnueabihf-gnatlink: error when calling /home/savvas/opt/GNAT/gnat-gpl-2016-raspberrypi-linux-linux-bin/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
   arm-linux-gnueabihf-gnatmake: *** link failed.
   ```

Is the linker looking for a **clib** (or some other filename?) file somewhere in the library path or is there something else going on? I'm new to gcc compilation/linking and am trying to make sense of this.

Any pointers, much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using this particular version of the GNAT (cross-)compiler, you need to copy some additional files from your RPi 2 to the host first. The exact steps are explained in the [README](https://community.download.adacore.com/v1/18da74a0ac9df2753bfd9b3d2dcad6e3379825c2?filename=README.txt&rand=1263) file that accompanies the particular GNAT release. I copied the relevant section to the end of this answer for convenience.

That said, also consider developing your program on Ubuntu first using a more recent version of GNAT ([Community Edition](https://www.adacore.com/download/more) or [an FSF version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gnat)), then copy the source code the Raspberry Pi, and recompile it on the Pi itself. The GNAT FSF compiler (and related tools) that is available from the Debian repositories is also available on Raspberry Pi OS:

```
$ sudo apt install gnat gprbuild
```

Finally, you could also consider to use [Alire](https://alire.ada.dev/) (at least on the host). Alire has no official support for Raspberry Pi yet, but an experimental release is already available [here](https://github.com/reznikmm/aarch64-alire-index).

---

**Excerpt from the README file:**

> Raspberrypi 2 (hosted on Linux)
>
> - The GNAT GPL compiler for raspberrypi is a cross compiler, hosted on linux-x86 (or linux-x86_64).  You need to copy from the boards some library files.  The following script achieves that.  It should be executed from `<GNAT GPL>/arm-linux-gnueabihf` (the `RPI` variable is login@target):
>
>   ```
>   #!/bin/sh
>
>   RPI=pi@myboard
>
>   mkdir sysroot sysroot/lib sysroot/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
>   cd sysroot/lib
>   rsync -a $RPI:/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/{ld-*,lib?.*,lib?-*,libpthread*,librt*} arm-linux-gnueabihf
>   ln -s arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib?.* .
>   cd ../..
>   mkdir sysroot/usr sysroot/usr/lib sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
>   cd sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
>   rsync -a $RPI:/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf {crt*,libc.*,libc_no*,libpthread*} .
>   ln -s ../../../lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.* libm.so
>   ln -s ../../../lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/librt.so.* librt.so
>   cd ..
>   ln -s arm-linux-gnueabihf/* .
>   ```
>
>   Before running a GNAT GPL tool, set `ENV_PREFIX` variable like this:
>
>   ```
>   export ENV_PREFIX=<GNAT GPL>/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot
>   ```

Comment: Sugestion#1 worked like a charm, thank you! (a small typo on the second rsync command as it fails due to a missing "/") Not sure I've actually got this on my local <GNAT GPL> dir to be honest, as greping for something like "RPI=" doesn't bring back any results. Maybe I downloaded some other version? Will give suggestion#2 a try as well as developing on GNAT Studio and compiling on the target certainly sounds more straightforward.  Alire was the first thing I tried but it was giving back some weird git error of "community indexes not found" or something along those lines, so I gave up :)